# how to place two collection views on top of a UIView with a UIImage view in between

Tags: xcode, collectionview

iOS Simulator Screen shot Jun 19, 2013 2.43.43 PM.png![Main Storyboard description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKD0N.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really simple. In your collection view `datasource` methods, make sure you distinguish between the two views by keeping strong references to the views e.g. as properties:

```
if (collectionView == _topCollectionView) {
   // provide the data for the top view
}
else {
   // provide the data for the bottom view
}
```

Do the same in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. Determine which collection view has been interacted with, change the appropriate data in for the other one and reload and/or update your image view.

You need to use a standard view controller and add the delegate and datasource declarations manually.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController 
         <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>
```

Comment: thank you. this worked with NSLog but did not populate the image view with the image from the plist.

Comment: Great. That means that updating the image view is a separate bug. You should accept the answer and ask a new question.

Comment: Mundi, forgot to mark as answer. Thanks again for your help. Any input on the other question would be appreciated